# $\{\infty\}$ open in $\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ with $d(a,b)=|\arctan a-\arctan b|$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X=\mathbb N\cup\{+\infty\}$. I want to find two metrices inducing different topologies.

Let $d_1$ be the discrete metric then all subsets of $X$ are open. (in particular $\{+\infty\}$)

But now I am having some troubles two find another metric $d_2$. I've tried $d_2(a,b)=|\arctan a-\arctan b|$ and to consider $\{+\infty\}$. Any help why $\{+\infty\}$ isn't open?

Comment: Hint: Show the sequence $a_n=n$ converges in $(X,d_2)$ and identify the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metric $d_2$ needs to be defined on the whole space. Are you taking $\arctan(\infty) = \frac \pi 2$? I'll assume that's the case.

In order for $\{\infty\}$ to be open, there must be $\epsilon > 0$ satisfying 
$B(\infty,\epsilon) \subset \{\infty\}$

However, for every $\epsilon > 0$ you have
$$B(\infty,\epsilon) = \{b \in X : d_x(\infty,b) < \epsilon\} = \{b \in X : \arctan b > \frac \pi 2 - \epsilon\} = (\tan(\tfrac \pi 2 - \epsilon),\infty]$$

Thus $\{\infty\}$ is not open.

Comment: how do you get an intervall at the end? it should be something in $\mathbb N\cup\{+\infty\}$ (maybe an intersection here?)

Comment: The interval is a simple notation for the set $$(\tan(\tfrac \pi 2 - \epsilon),\infty] = \bigg\{n \in \mathbb N \cup \{\infty\} : \tan (\tfrac \pi 2 - \epsilon) < n \le \infty\bigg\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

A priori, $\arctan \infty$ is not defined, hence you failed to define $d_2$ where one of $a,b$ is infty. However, we may use the limit to make the pretty definitoin $\arctan\infty:=\frac\pi 2$. With this definition, $\{\infty\}$ is not open. The $\epsilon$-ball around $\infty$ is precisely the set of $a$ with $\arctan a>\frac\pi2-\epsilon$, i.e. the set $(\tan(\frac\pi2-\epsilon),\infty]$.

We might make a less natural definition of $\arctan\infty:=42$. With this definition, $\{\infty\}$ is open!